# Im a static fobic

Tags: java, static

Well from all the things I have read about how evil static variables can be, I became a static fobic.
I'm so afraid to put a static variable to one big project because I feel I might regret it, even though it will make the code easier.
I never understood when its okay to use a static so I try to never use them.
I'm developing this big game, and a static `entityManager` would be so helpful, instead I ended up passing `entityManager` instance to every class that need it, but sometimes its so hard to pass it. And it would be so easy to just do `EntityManager.addEntity(Entity);`

I know that there are topics like "When its okay to use static?" but it seems theres no easy way to explain this in a easy way to understand.

Can someone tell me in a easy-english way, when its okay to use static variables?

english is not my primary language, so please do keep that in mind.

Comment: Passing an `entityManager` instance is the way to go, but you can make it easier using tools like dependency injection.  You're doing the right thing.

Comment: In my opinion you should not use static entity manger if you're creating it yourself because entitymanager is not thread-safe. Saying that if you're already on a container managed environment you will be safe to use it because containers like Spring manages the thread-safety of entity manager with context aware proxy

Answer (score 2):

1) it is totally ok to use static instances with a final keyword as a read-only constants

2) if you want singleton services which are accessible in various components it's better to use dependency injection frameworks like Spring DI, CDI or Guice to manage them

Answer (score 2):

`static` is great for stateless, pure methods, like `String.format()`

`static` is great for constants, like:

```
public static final double PI = 3.14159;
```

`static` is great for private fields for which there can by logical definition only ever be a single value, like the list of values in an `enum` (and the public methods used to access these private fields).

While you *usually* only have one EntityManager in an application, there's nothing wrong with having more than one. You could have 3, or 3 million. Because there is not strictly **one** entity manager, it should not be static. Passing it around is the proper way to handle it.

Comment: Minor side note: be careful with `static` methods that break in unit test environments. So it is not only about being "stateless"; it is also about "runs fine" when called in the context of your unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

When you use static stuff, you are introducing tight coupling in your code base. If that static stuff is private and internal to a class, that is not a problem and there is nothing to be afraid of. However, for all others it makes it impossible for you to provide alternative implementations and now you can't have proper unit tests.

Now, if it seems too much work for you to pass that manager all around, believe me it brings much flexibility. On the other hand, if there are too many managers that are being passed around, reconsider your classes and maybe split them into smaller parts. In the ideal case, each class should be responsible from one thing only.